# Видимость метода в dll

Tags: c#

Реализовал метод(удалить) в некоторой dll, метод вызывается в ContextMenuStrip. Dll используется в разных приложениях, и в некоторых из них этот метод должен быть виден в ContextMenuStrip, а в некоторых нет. Как это реализовать. Думаю с помощью оператора условия и какой-то буферной переменной, которая в нужном приложении имеет значение true, а в остальных случаях false, но что-то не получается пока-что

Comment: Если правильно понял, то как вариант подписывайте свои приложения, а в библиотеке указывайте publicKeyToken тех приложений, которым разрешено использовать метод.

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ToString() Вызываете данный метод после того как подпишите приложение. Он вернет publicKeyToken. А дальше добавляете в библиотеку.

Comment: А почему бы не выпустить две DLL, в одной из которых определить метод расширения?